# s~applicationid: uncaught application failure

Tags: google-app-engine

Me and a small group of people are using a remote git repository to hold our GAE project. The others have no problem deploying the project, but whenever I deploy, it seems that I can't access any pages involving JSPs or servlet-related pages. I am left with a blank page and in the html:

`<title>s~applicationid: uncaught application failure</title>`

Does this have something to do with the way my JSPs are compiling? Since my workmates have no problem deploying, it must be something local, but I have no idea where to start with this problem. Can anyone help?

Edit: Here is a piece of the error log given by GAE's admin panel. http://pastebin.com/mRddXgiz

Comment: The error in the admin panel is extremely long, this is only a piece of it. I'll add it into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error log, the critical piece of the error message is likely this:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

You're seeing this because you're compiling with Java 7, but should be using Java 6.

Comment: I changed from JRE7 to JRE6 but that didn't change it, was that the right thing to change?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZFSqy926 It seems to be the same error, could it perhaps be that I may be using 32-bit eclipse and 64-bit jre?

Comment: @theeggman85 seems like you are using different versions of jdk and jre. both should be of the same version.